# How to stop ansible from hopping to second task until first task is executed successfully?

Tags: ansible

My playbook looks like this:

```
--- 
  - hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: false
  - name: execute task 1
    shell: nohup sh test001.sh >> nohup.out 2>&1 &
    async: 120
    poll: 10
  - name: read generated log for task 1
    shell: cat test001result*
    register: execution_status
  - name: If task 1 failed
    shell: nohup sh test002.sh >> nohup.out 2>&1 &
    when: execution_status.stdout.find('success') == -1
  - name: If task 1 passed
    shell: nohup sh test003.sh >> nohup.out 2>&1 &
    when: execution_status.stdout.find('success') != -1
```

Now task 1 takes 60 seconds to complete i.e. test001result is generated after 60 sec at least. Despite having added async for 120 seconds, ansible execution continues and test002.sh is executed despite success of task1. This is because the log has not been generated (show 0 bytes).

How to rectify this issue?

Comment: See [Async and Polling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-actions-and-polling).

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Make sure your question follows these rules. IMHO, this is the only way you could expect reasonable answer.

Comment: @VladimirBotka : I have added the playbook details here, Can you suggest anything now ?

Answer (score 1):

Given the scripts

```bash
shell> cat test001.sh
echo $(date) test_01 started
sleep 3
echo 'success' > test001result
echo $(date) test_01 finished
exit 0
```

```bash
shell> cat test002.sh
echo $(date) test_02 started
sleep 3
echo $(date) test_02 finished
exit 0
```

```bash
shell> cat test003.sh
echo $(date) test_03 started
sleep 3
echo $(date) test_03 finished
exit 0
```

In the playbook, don't detach the process

```bash
  nohup sh test001.sh >> nohup.out 2>&1 &
```

Simply run it

```bash
  sh test001.sh >> nohup.out 2>&1
```

For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: execute task 1
    shell: sh test001.sh >> nohup.out 2>&1
    async: 20
    poll: 5
    ignore_errors: true

  - name: read generated log for task 1
    shell: cat test001result
    register: execution_status
    ignore_errors: true
  - debug:
      var: execution_status.stdout

  - name: If task 1 failed
    shell: nohup sh test002.sh >> nohup.out 2>&1 &
    when: execution_status.stdout is not search('success')

  - name: If task 1 passed
    shell: nohup sh test003.sh >> nohup.out 2>&1 &
    when: execution_status.stdout is search('success')
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [execute task 1] ****
changed: [localhost]

TASK [read generated log for task 1] ****
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  execution_status.stdout: success

TASK [If task 1 failed] ****
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [If task 1 passed] ****
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=4 changed=3 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=1 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

```bash
shell> cat nohup.out 
Tue 25 Aug 2020 09:50:35 PM CEST test_01 started
Tue 25 Aug 2020 09:50:38 PM CEST test_01 finished
Tue 25 Aug 2020 09:50:41 PM CEST test_03 started
Tue 25 Aug 2020 09:50:44 PM CEST test_03 finished
```

In the same way, `test002.sh` shall be run when `test001.sh` doesn't succeed.

---

The directives `async` and `poll` serve the purpose of running a process that might not end in a reasonable amount of time. Let's test this case and increase the sleep to 30 seconds in test001.sh. In this case, both first 2 tasks will fail. The task `execute task 1` will fail because of `async` timeout and the task `read generated log for task 1` will fail because of the missing file `test001result`. We have to set `ignore_errors: true` for these 2 tasks. Now the playbook gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [execute task 1] ****
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: async task did not complete within the requested time - 20s
...ignoring

TASK [read generated log for task 1] ****
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  cmd: cat test001result
  delta: '0:00:00.003367'
  end: '2020-08-25 22:11:56.422448'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2020-08-25 22:11:56.419081'
  stderr: 'cat: test001result: No such file or directory'
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
...ignoring

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  execution_status.stdout: ''

TASK [If task 1 failed] ****
changed: [localhost]

TASK [If task 1 passed] ****
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=4 changed=2 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=1 rescued=0 ignored=2
```

```bash
shell> cat nohup.out 
Tue 25 Aug 2020 10:11:35 PM CEST test_01 started
Tue 25 Aug 2020 10:11:56 PM CEST test_02 started
Tue 25 Aug 2020 10:11:59 PM CEST test_02 finished
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. The key was not to detach the process with nohup. But this leads to another question, in one of my test cases I found out that task 1 may take 4 days to complete, ansible documentation provides no hard limit for async, but will it be a good way to handle such a long running task this way?

Comment: If a task takes 4 days to complete you might want to apply a [monitor](https://linuxhandbook.com/server-monitoring-tools/) of your choice. You can use [Monitoring modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/list_of_monitoring_modules.html#monitoring-modules) or other Ansible modules to configure the monitor from the same playbook on the fly.